# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I am trying to create a web server on my ubuntu 18.04 so i installed Apache2 
but i can't start it.
Here's what appeared when i run the `systemctl status apache2.service` command

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-02-22 13:58:09 CET; 34s ago
  Process: 2791 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

```
Feb 22 13:58:09 moemen apachectl[2791]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's
Feb 22 13:58:09 moemen apachectl[2791]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not b
Feb 22 13:58:09 moemen apachectl[2791]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not b
Feb 22 13:58:09 moemen apachectl[2791]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Feb 22 13:58:09 moemen apachectl[2791]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Feb 22 13:58:09 moemen apachectl[2791]: Action 'start' failed.
Feb 22 13:58:09 moemen apachectl[2791]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Feb 22 13:58:09 moemen systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 22 13:58:09 moemen systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 22 13:58:09 moemen systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I'm new at this can you please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure no other web servers (like nginx) are listening on the same port or try changing the port.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I also faced same problem.

First check

```
$ sudo systemctl status nginx
```

If `nginx` is active then stop this with

```
$ sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

then again try to start apache2 server in different terminal.

Comment: @Greenoline, thanks. I somehow installed nginx after apache2, removing nginx-core, nginx-common solved my problem

Comment: Not a generic solution. Better to check apache logs and netstat for port, to proceed with solution.

Answer (score 8):

first remove apache2

`sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2`
`sudo apt-get autoremove`

after that if there files (.conf) /etc/sites-available remove them using

```
rm example.com.conf
```

then install again
`sudo apt-get install apache2`

now it will fixed
check it now
`sudo ufw allow 'Apache'`
`sudo systemctl status apache2`

Comment: After spending several days, troubleshooting my problem stopped with this answer.  Thank you!  (HINT: In addition to removing and reinstalling apache2, should remove /etc/apache2 directory as it contains remnants from the now-removed installation.)

Answer (score 4):

Let me give a more general answer than the first 2. One possible problem with Apache is, when we try to run it, it may fail because port 80 is used by another software:

- a common case is nginx which is covered by Devashish Mishra
- in my case it was a server app that I deployed (in node.js, I had to tell pm2 to stop it)
- in general, you may want to find what uses port 80. This may be done like Chi.C.J.Rajeeva Lochana has suggested: install netstat if you don't have it (`sudo apt install net-tools`), use it: `sudo netstat -antup | grep 80`. It will show some lines which may include `:::80` or `<your IP>:80` which will tell what is listening to the port

Once you've found what listens to the 80 port, you have to decide what to do with it. For instance, if that's nginx and you don't use it, you may go like Devashish Mishra has suggested: just stop it (`sudo systemctl stop nginx`). Likewise, you can stop or kill (`sudo killall -9 program-name`) other programs. However, if you need them, you'll also need to further configure Apache and rerun them (the exact steps highly depend on the case).

Answer (score 2):

### Please read this carefully.

**Perform the following command, and if you see it is apache, then do the following below the command.**
Note: You need to install the net-tools package before you could run netstat. Run `sudo apt install net-tools` to install it.

```
sudo netstat -antup | grep 80
```

You should check the line with something like `<Your IP>:80`.
Please note that this might also happen when you uninstall Apache when it is running.

The command could be:

```
sudo killall -9 program-name
```

Replace program-name with the program's name if the program running on port 80 is not stoppable. Let me know it it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found this problem and was able to solve it by creating a folder `/var/log/apache2`, I checked in the `/var/log/` folder, it turns out that there is no apache2 folder, just like in the case of mysql that won't start.

seen from your log that

`Feb 22 13:58:09 moment apachectl[2791]: AH00015: Unable to open logs`

maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

Also, check your certificates. If you look at the apache log, it might tell you that the certificates do not match.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, stop or remove `nginx`, then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-bin apache2-utils apache2-data
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

you're welcome it's done.

Answer (score -2):

1. On your terminal.
2. Type: `sudo stop /etc/init.d/apache2`

The response will be:

> Stopping apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.

3. Now start the server:

```bash
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

If you installed lamp correctly this should work